# PyQt5 QPixmap is Null with valid file

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtgui, qpixmap

I am trying to load an icon into a tool button. I need to first create a pixmap so I can add it to the QIcon, which then is added to the tool button. However, the pixmap is always null and nothing gets displayed on the tool button except for the default text of "..."

Take a look at this

```
file = ":/icons/refresh.jpg"
if QtCore.QFile.exists(file):
    print("File exists")
else:
    print("Does not exist")
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(file)
print(pixmap.isNull())

>>>File exists
>>>True
```

Why is the pixmap not being created when a valid file is given?

I am running Python 3.4 in a virtualenv with PyQt5 v5.5 on Windows 10

Comment: You can use [QImageReader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html) to check the validity of the file, and possibly also detect the image format.

Answer (score 0):

ekhumoro pushed me in the right direction with QImageReader, where I checked the file formats with supportedImageFormats(). This led me to this post https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/131

I discovered that since I am using a virtualenvironment, the Python interpreter was in a location that was unknown to the qt.conf file, which had the wrong prefix for the interpreter path. By changing my prefix to my PyQt5 folder relative to the venv folder, I was able to get Qt to load the .jpg image format .dll which now displays the image.